# List all Anti-Virus via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a script to list and check if multiple Anti-Virus are installed on a machine which is working fine. Is there a better way to make it more simpler that having a long code?

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct >>         
C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt
$AVName1 = "Avast"
$AVName2 = "AVG"
$AVName3 = "Avira"
$AVName4 = "Bitdefender"
$AVName5 = "ZoneAlarm"
$AVName6 = "Immunet"
$AVName7 = "ClamWin"
$AVName8 = "Comodo"
$AVName9 = "Dr.Web"
$AVName10 = "ESET"
$AVName11 = "F-Secure"
$AVName12 = "F-PROT"
$AVName13 = "G DATA"
$AVName14 = "Kaspersky"
$AVName15 = "Malwarebytes"
$AVName16 = "McAfee"
$AVName17 = "Windows Defender"
$AVName18 = "NANO"
$AVName19 = "Norton"
$AVName20 = "Spyware"
$AVName21 = "Panda"
$AVName22 = "360 Total Security"
$AVName23 = "Sophos"
$AVName24 = "Titanium"
$AVName25 = "TrustPort"
$AVName26 = "Vba32"
$AVName27 = "Viper"
$AVName28 = "Sentinel"
$AVName29 = "Webroot"
$hostname = "hostname"
$Text1 = "instanceGuid*"
$Text2 = "pathToSignedProductExe*"
$Text3 = "pathToSignedReportingExe*"
$Text4 = "productState*"
$Text5 = "timestamp*"
$Text6 = "PSComputerName*"
$AV1 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName1" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV2 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName2" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV3 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName3" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV4 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName4" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV5 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName5" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV6 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName6" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV7 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName7" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV8 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName8" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV9 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName9" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV10 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName10" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV11 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName11" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV12 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName12" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV13 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName13" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV14 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName14" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV15 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName15" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV16 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName16" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV17 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName17" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV18 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName18" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV19 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName19" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV20 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName20" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV21 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName21" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV22 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName22" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV23 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName23" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV24 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName24" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV25 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName25" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV26 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName26" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV27 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName27" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV28 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName28" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV29 = Select-String -Path C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt -Pattern "$AVName29" -SimpleMatch -Quiet
$AV = Get-Content C:\temp\AVInstalled.txt | Select-String -Pattern "$Text1", "$Text2", "$Text3", "$Text4", "$Text5", "$Text6" -NotMatch
if ($AV1 -Or $AV2 -Or $AV3 -Or $AV4 -Or $AV5 -Or $AV6 -Or $AV7 -Or $AV8 -Or $AV9 -Or $AV10 -Or $AV11 -Or $AV12 -Or $AV13 -Or $AV14 -Or $AV15 -Or $AV16 -Or $AV17 -Or $AV18 -Or $AV19 -Or $AV20 -Or $AV21 -Or $AV22 -Or $AV23 -Or $AV24 -Or $AV25 -Or $AV26 -Or $AV27 -Or $AV28 -Or $AV29 -eq 'True' )
                {
                echo "[INFO] Multiple Anti-Virus are installed on this machine: ";
                echo "$(Get-Date) - [INFO] $AV."
                }
            else{ 
                echo "There's only one Antiv-Virus installed on this machine:"
                echo "$(Get-Date) - [INFO] $AV."
                }
```

Also, the result of $AV shows like this:

```
[INFO] Multiple Anti-Virus are installed on this machine: 
12/28/2021 17:25:50 - [INFO]   displayName              : Webroot SecureAnywhere  displayName              : Bitdefender Endpoint Security Tools Antimalware  displayName              : Windows Defender  displayName              : Webroot SecureAnywhere   .
```

How can I remove the extra spaces and add a new line to each result and show it like this?

```
[INFO] Multiple Anti-Virus are installed on this machine: 
12/28/2021 17:25:50 - [INFO]   displayName: Webroot SecureAnywhere  
displayName: Bitdefender Endpoint Security Tools Antimalware  
displayName: Windows Defender  
displayName: Webroot SecureAnywhere   .
```

Thank you,

Comment: Why are you text parsing when `CimInstance` returns objects that can be easily manipulated?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'm not sure how I can manipulate the result of `CimInstance` that's why I did the text parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is one way to grab & show that info ...

the code ...

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

$AVList = @(Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root/SecurityCenter2' -ClassName 'AntivirusProduct')

switch ($AVList.Count)
#switch (0)
#switch (3)
    {
    0 {Write-Warning 'No AV product detected.'}
    1 {
        Write-Host 'There is just one AV product installed.'
        Write-Host ('    DisplayName = {0}' -f $AVList.displayName)
        }
    default
        {
        Write-Warning ('There are {0} AV products installed on this system.' -f $AVList.Count)
        Write-Warning ('    DisplayNames = {0}' -f ($AVList.displayName -join ', '))
        }
    }
```

on my system with one AV product ...

```
There is just one AV product installed.
    DisplayName = Windows Defender
```

if i comment out the 1st `switch` test and use the `3` value, i get this ...

```
WARNING: There are 1 AV products installed on this system.
WARNING:     DisplayNames = Windows Defender
```

obviously, the count is showing the real one, but you can see the result would be the number of AV items AND a comma-delimited list of the display names.

what the code does ...

- tells PoSh that the script needs to run as admin
  if that aint the case, PoSh will refuse to run this code.
- grabs the list of AV items via a CIM call & stores that list in a $Var
- the `@()` wrapped around the above line forces the result to be an array
  there are times when it helps to force such ... in this case it makes certain that the `.Count` property will be there AND be accurate.
- uses a `switch` statement to choose what to do based on the count of AV items in the $AVList var
- if `0`, say so
  here's hoping that doesn't show up for any of your systems. [*grin*]
- if `1`, say so and list the AV display name
- if any thing else [the `default` value], show the count and a list of the display names

Comment: thanks @Lee_Dailey. I'll test it now on my environment.

Comment: @IamBayMax - you are most welcome! glad to help a tad now and then ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have `Get-CimInstance` available for testing but it should be as easy as this:

```
$av = Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct
if($av.Count -gt 1) # if more than 1 AV was found, show them
{
    $av | ForEach-Object -Begin {
        '[INFO] Multiple Anti-Virus are installed on this machine:'
        '[INFO] - {0}' -f [datetime]::now
    } -Process {
        'DisplayName: {0}' -f $_.DisplayName
    }
}
```

---

One thing to note, you're using `-eq 'True'`, [*booleans*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_booleans) in PowerShell are `$true` and `$false` (`-eq $true`) however in your code it shouldn't be needed at all:

```
if($false -or $false -or $true){ $true } # => $true
```

What's happening on your code is that whenever one of the variables (*`$av1`, `$av2`...*) is `$true` then the *boolean* is tested for equality with a *string* (the literal `'True'`) and, any *string* when evaluated is `$true` except for `''` or `[string]::Empty`:

```
$false -or $true -eq 'anystring' # => $true
$true -eq 'anystring'            # => $true
$true -eq [string]::Empty        # => $false
$true -eq ''                     # => $false
```

Comment: it works. it can now display the $AV result the way I wanted. thank you.

Comment: @IamBayMax happy to help, please see my edit, unrelated to the question but you should be aware of it